# Is there a way to add a table constraint based on one of its columns value?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

To be more specific. I have this table for events

```sql
create table event(
 id NUMERIC(3) PRIMARY KEY,
 date DATE
)
```

I need to add another column (`canceled`) that accepts only `0` and `1` values. The problem here is that the column also needs a constraint that doesn't allow events before 1.01.2021 to be cancelled (meaning that `cancel` value cannot be `1`(true) for an event whose date is, for example, 15.09.2020). Any hints? This is the 'closest' I got, but I know it's wrong and by searching on other threads, I learned that queries are not allowed inside a constraint.
What I tried (which I know is not correct as it doesn't allow adding entries with their date before 1.01.2021):

```
ALTER TABLE event
ADD canceled number(1) DEFAULT 0 CHECK(canceled in (0,1));

ALTER TABLE event
ADD CONSTRAINT C_event_canceled CHECK(date >= to_date('01/01/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

Forgot to mention, I cannot use any functions or something related, jus plain queries.

Comment: Why not `check(not((date < to_date('01/01/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and (canceled = 1)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> doesn't allow events before 1.01.2021 to be canceled

Mureinik's answer is correct.  However, this version is closer to how you express what you want to check:

```
check (not (cancelled = 1 and date < date '2021-01-01') )
```

Note that Oracle uses `date` as a prefix to date constants.  In addition, `date` is a data type -- that makes it a very bad choice for a column name.  I would suggest:

```
check (not (cancelled = 1 and event_date < date '2021-01-01') )
```

Answer (score 2):

A check constraint can have a condition based on multiple columns. Here, you want to allow any date if `canceled` is `0`, or a specific date range if it isn't:

```
ALTER TABLE event
ADD CONSTRAINT C_event_canceled CHECK(
    canceled = 0 OR
    date >= to_date('01/01/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not think about that, the only solutions that I found required queries in CHECK constraint